# Build NuGet package from ASP NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have solution with four projects:

1. `FAPIServer.Storage`
2. `FAPIServer`
3. `FAPIServer.EntityFramework`
4. `FAPIServer.Web`

The `1`, `2` and `3` are library project and the last `4` is ASP NET Core project. I planned that if I will be publishing the appropriate NuGet packages, then I will just convert the `4` project to library project and add necessary dependecies on ASP NET Core by referencing them as NuGet packages. But it occured that most of necessary packages are marked as deprecated.

I know I can use `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` in `.csproj` but I'm not sure if it's a good way to achieve my goal. Using this the `.exe` file will also be included in NuGet? It seems to me that it will be generally heavier than just library project.

So what I need to do to build NuGet package from ASP NET Core project or how can I reference  whole ASP NET Core framework in my library project?

*I'm using NET 7.*

Comment: Actually, to build nuget package you should have a class library project or even you can create a asp.net core project along with required framework and include your nuget package there. You can [`get the more details here in this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework).

Comment: The linked docs is for non-SDK style ("legacy") projects, which I wouldn't recommend. But yes, create a class library project (`dotnet new classlib`), and then you can `dotnet pack` it. If you need to access AspNetCore APIs, add a FrameworkReference as the docs explain: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework

Comment: Yes, the FrameworkReference is what I was looking for! Thank you so much!